# How can I travel between Schengen countries with my new passport without a visa since I lost the old one with the visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, europe

I am a student here in Spain and I lost my passport with the Schengen visa, I got a new passport from the embassy but it’s without a visa and I am thinking of travelling somewhere in europe, how can I do that without the visa?